# replaceAll not working as expected when escaping special characters

Tags: java

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String searchKeyword="Legal'%_";
        String specialChars[]={"_","%","'"};
        for(int i=0;i<specialChars.length;i++)
           searchKeyword=searchKeyword.replaceAll(specialChars[i],"\\"+specialChars[i]);
        System.out.println(searchKeyword);

    }
}
```

This snippet is trying to escape some special characters, but the issue is that searchKeyword is not getting new replaced String.

Its output should be Legal\'\%_, but I am getting the original string only as output.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

[`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) works with a regex :

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.

What you need to replace a substring in an input String by a specific String is : [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.